# List of Crossover Sites for those who enjoy (or at least tolerate) Christianity SE

Tags: discussion

I was thinking of coming here and drumming up support for the [homeschooling proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114491/homeschool), but I thought maybe it would be better to have a more broad discussions.

What other sites might people who enjoy Christianity.SE also enjoy participating in?

Please list a proposal you like from Area51 or other network site and why you think people who participate on Christianity.SE would like it too.

Comment: Any reason to restrict to Area 51 proposals, other than the obvious need to garner supporters?

Comment: @freds no, not really - but garnering supporters is the hope I had for this post

Answer (score 7):

## [Semitic Languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113173/semitic-languages?referrer=E7543yclX-MBmqgt1wfCkA2)

If you want to study the Old Testament closely, knowledge of biblical Hebrew is vital. Hebrew originated in a melting pot of different cultures and different languages, so sooner or later you will also benefit from knowledge of Aramaic, Ugaritic, Phoenician and other languages from Syria-Palestine. These are all Semitic languages.

The Semitic Languages proposal aims to provide answers to questions about any Semitic language, dead or alive. There are two main reasons for this: (1) much more than for Indo-European, there was a lot of language contact in Semitic languages, so studying any language will almost certainly benefit from knowledge about others; (2) previous iterations of separate Hebrew and Arabic proposals have shown that there is not enough audience for separate sites.

Answer (score 6):

### [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)

Instead of attempting to answer what Christianity, or Denomination X understands a Biblical text to mean, this site attempts to understand how *specific passages* a of text would have been received in its' [*original*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZkY46DB1Hk&t=22s) [context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLQmgPT-xOU&t=163s) and to explore hermeneutic techniques and principles and the science and art of Biblical Interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

### [Greek Languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language)

If you want to study the New Testament closely, knowledge of Koine Greek is vital. The Hebrew Old Testament was also translated to Greek in the Septuagint, so this can aid not just in understanding the New Testament, but also help to elucidate how Jewish Scholarship understood and interpreted the Old Testament around the time of Jesus.

The Greek Languages proposal aims to provide answers to questions about any version of the Greek language, currently or in antiquity - including [Koine Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek).

Answer (score 5):

### [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/)

The Latin  stack exchange provides a place where you can ask translation questions about Roman Catholic writings, the writings of Early Church Fathers and even some Koine Greek questions (until the [Greek proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) gets off the ground that is!)

Answer (score 4):

## Homeschool

Religious education is [one of the primary reasons](https://www.responsiblehomeschooling.org/homeschooling-101/reasons-parents-homeschool/) people homeschool their children.  There is a lot of overlap between Christian education and homeschooling - especially considering the fact that parents educating their students aren't necessarily going to know the answers to their religious education questions.

So, Christianity.SE and a potential Homeschool.SE would go well together.

Answer (score 4):

## [Self-directed learning](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113111/self-directed-learning)

Highly technical religious studies will require a familiarity with academia not typically known unless formally involved in it, therefore, a resource to help find the right resources may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

## [Paleontology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109549/paleontology)

Especially among YEC believers, the science sites that deal specifically with evolution or very aged Earth theories may find particular interest.

Answer (score 4):

**[History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35010/what-advantages-did-catholic-missionaries-to-the-indians-have-over-protestant-mi/35016#35016)**

Some historical questions about Christianity have already been posed on this site. Historical buffs might be able to answer certain historical questions that are hard to answer.

Answer (score 3):

### [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)

Christianity has it's foundations built upon the older religion of Judaism. It can therefore be elucidating to study the roots and origins of the Christian faith by studying the teachings of Rabbis and the faith of Judaism to better understand the origins and meanings of Christian beliefs - as well as better understanding the daily life of the Messiah upon which the Christian faith is based and the beliefs and lives of his two major audience demographics in the New Testament.

Answer (score 2):

## [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)

Over on Literature SE, there are several tags that relate to Christianity, such as [C. S. Lewis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-s-lewis) and [Religion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion).  And since the site's scope is purposefully broad, many other questions about Christian literature could be asked/answered there as well.